# How to set perform_caching dynamically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I want to control whether to perform caching at runtime.

I wrote an admin action like the following to test the idea (trying to set it to true):

```
  def togglecache
    Rails.configuration.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    render :index
  end
```

However after setting it, caching is still not taking effect.

How to achieve this, if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = true
  Rails.cache.clear
  load 'app/controllers/name_controller.rb'
```

Comment: Is there a way to reload all controllers? Also how would this work for caching in models?